# Reloading a div removes it and does not show anything

Tags: html, jquery, typescript

When I try this line of code:

```
$("#topleft").load(location.href + " #topleft");
```

it removes the topleft div instead of reloading it.

I am executing the code above in a typescript file (specification.ts) but the HTML that contains topleft (view.html) is connected to a different typescript file (view.ts). Is this the reason why my div does not get reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Since the div you are trying to reload is in a different location, you will need to use the location that you are trying to reload from (in this case view.html) so the load function will look like this
`$("#topleft").load("view.html #topleft");`

location.href refers to the page executing the script, so this effectively will do nothing (since reloading the div from the same page will result in the same content).

Comment: I read your question again and realized I may have misunderstood something. You mentioned that the div you are trying to reload is in "view.html". Is this the same page that the script is executing in?

Comment: No its not in the same page and I am thinking this may be my problem. I am trying to upload a div in a different page. I had tried using document.URL and got the same results. I got round this issue by using the DOM and setting the display property to BLOCK or NONE to show or hide the div. Would still like to know if its possible to use the JQuery .load to refresh a div that is located in another page?